# Block variation was switched back to the root block after its attributes are updated

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am writing a WordPress plugin that register a variation of the core query block. The variation add `include` to the query:

```javascript
    attributes: {
        namespace: MASTER_QUERY_LOOP,
        query: {
            include: []
        },
    },
```

After I insert the variation into the editor and do some settings of the variation block, I update the block attributes:

```javascript
    const newInclude = [1]; // just a test ID
    setAttributes({query: {include: newInclude}});
```

I expect my block variation `Master Query Loop` will show only one post with the ID=1, but it was switched back to the core `Query Loop` block and keep showing the loading indicator. Can anyone help me to explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block variations require an [`isActive`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/extending-the-query-loop-block/#making-gutenberg-recognize-your-variation) property so the Gutenberg Editor can tell if the block is the default block or a variation.

If `isActive` is not defined, the Editor matches the block as the default - this is why you see the default query block as selected instead of your variant.

When the query block continually displays the loading indicator, it means some part of the query is invalid. In this case `include:[1]` is not a valid query parameter to get a post by id. A better query parameter for your scenario is `postIn:[1]` which accepts an array of post ids.

**Eg.**

```jsx
const MASTER_QUERY_LOOP = 'my-plugin/custom-query'; // Should be unique

registerBlockVariation( 'core/query', {
    ...
    attributes: {
        namespace: MASTER_QUERY_LOOP,
        query: {
            postIn: []
        },
    },
    isActive: ( { namespace, query } ) => {
        return (
            namespace === MASTER_QUERY_LOOP
            // Using just the namespace is fine for query block variations
        );
    },
});
```

NB. If the default of `postIn:[]` is an empty array, `postIn` will return `has_posts()` as true. If you then set `perPage:1` in the attributes, it will return just the most recent post.

Reference: [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters)